# Prove that $f(x)=\frac{3}{4}(2x-x^2)$ if $x \in (0,2)$, $f(x)=0$ otherwise, is a density

Tags: probability-theory, density-function

> Given is the function $f(x)=\left\{\begin{matrix} \frac{3}{4}(2x-x^2)
> \text{ if } x \in (0,2)\\  0\;\;\;\text{ else } \end{matrix}\right.$
>
> Show that $f(x)$ is a density.

I think we need show that

1. $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}: f(x) \geq 0$
2. $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x) dx=1$

---

1. Is satisfied because in interval $(0,2)$ we have that $2x$ grows at least as fast as $x^2$ so the product will be positive for sure and multiplied by $\frac{3}{4}$ it will still be positive.
2. $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x) dx = \int_{0}^{2}\frac{3}{4}\left(2x-x^2\right)dx = \int_{0}^{2} \frac{3}{2}x - \frac{3}{4}x^2 dx = \left[\frac{3}{4}x^2 - \frac{1}{4}x^3\right]_{0}^{2} = 3-2-(0) = 1$$

---

Is it good like that? I have doubt in step 1. but I don't know how to do it more clear / better maybe you can tell me if all is good like that? Because I would do same in exam I write soon :s

Comment: yes, you got it correct

Comment: @user29418 Thank you for answer me you sure that also 1. is good because I don't know correctors can say you don't show it clear or good enough?

Comment: The rationale is sound, you may try to complete the square to show that the minimum value is non-negative.

Comment: @BGM I don't understand how can I complete the square?

Comment: Your proof of $1$ is a bit hand-wavy. You can write $2x-x^2=1-(x-1)^2$ so this shows that that $2x-x^2>0$ when $|x-1|<1$, that is, when $x\in(0,2).$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Do really mean $x \in \left[0,2\right]$ because I have given interval $(0,2)$ instead?

Comment: Yeah, I wrote $\geq 0$ initially, but re-edited for only positive values.

Comment: Great thank you so much everyone :)

Comment: Of course, it is easier to say that $x$ is positive on $(0,2)$ and $2-x$ is positive on $(0,2)$, so $x(2-x)$ is positive on $(0,2)$.